# Trying to prevent a dead key from being typed from a Mac keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to create a shortcut using the combo <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, which normally types a dead key <kbd>ˆ</kbd>, I tried the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtInput").keydown(
       function (event) {
           if (event.which == 229 && event.altKey === true) {
               alert(event);
               event.preventDefault();
               event.stopPropagation();
           }
       }
   ); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtInput" type="text" />
```

The code inside the condition executes, but <kbd>ˆ</kbd> is still typed in my `"#txtInput"`.
Is it possible to prevent this text from being typed?

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Came across this post while searching a way to prevent a `Dead` key (like `'` used in a combination to get special characters, e.g. ā, ē, ī, etc) from being entered in to a text `input` on MacOS

None of the solutions out there worked as OP mentioned - they were unable to prevent the Browser/OS from starting the character combination

One hacky way I found to do it is to blur the input on `Dead` keypress and then focus it back again after an insignificant delay. In my case this causes less flickering than removing the entered symbols after the fact by manipulating the `event.target.value`

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input')

input.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  console.log(e.key)

  if (e.key === 'Dead') {
    input.blur()
    setTimeout(() => input.focus())
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
```

This will also prevent the next special character that `'` transforms to from appearing in the input

Answer (score 2):

This is very keyboard layout-specific, and this maybe is not a generic solution, but you could do something like this to make ALT + I short-cut to work:

```js
function custom() {
  console.log('The short-cut executed');
}
let isDead = false;
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.altKey && e.code === 'KeyI') {
    custom();
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  if (isDead) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  isDead = (e.key === 'Dead');
});
```

```html
<input>
```

The dead key itself can't be prevented, but the character produced after the dead key. As many properties of the keyboard event are now deprecated, the code uses relatively new [code property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code), which will give the code of the physical key which was hit.

---

**EDIT**

As MacOS seems to refuse to prevent the default action of dead keys, you could use two events, one on `document` to trigger the shortcut, and another on inputs (or on `document` as well) to wipe out the caret (or any unwanted characters).

```js
function custom() {
  console.log('The short-cut executed');
}

// KeyDown for triggering the shortcut
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.altKey && e.code === 'KeyI') {
    custom();
  };
});

// Input for removing the dead key characters
$(document).on('input', 'input', e => {
  e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/\^/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
```

The both events are needed because when `keydown` is triggered, the value of the input is not updated yet. On the other hand, the event object of `input` event doesn't have `key/code` properties.

Comment: This is not working either. ```e.preventDefault();``` doesn't seem to be doing anything at all.

Comment: Also not an optimal solution since pressing ^ for more than once still allows me to enter it. At least on my windows machine. Pretty tricky question

Comment: @Aaron I can't reproduce that, on my keyboard the caret comes with SHIFT + ^ (scandinavian keyboard).

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful. I can use this as an example with my other hotkeys, but the only problem is that ```ˆ``` is still being typed in the input field, the same happens for all other dead keys {alt+e, alt+u, alt+n, alt+`} on my keyboard layout.

Comment: I get the idea, and it can work. But I don't think this is a general solution or one of the best practices. If I have to use this combo, this idea might actually be my only option. Thanks!

Comment: @KareemMohsen The general solution seems to be "no solution" for MacOS (Safari?). You can go with a single event (keyup) by adding the replace line to that event handler, but the caret flashes in the input shortly.

Comment: This is also a problem on windows. I have to detect the special dead character in e.data onInput and modify the event.target. Preventing/cancelling it does not work, even though the event has cancellable==true. Seems a really bad solution :/

Comment: This one worked for me both on Windows and Mac. Angular implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bjkrrk?file=src/app/only-numbers.directive.ts

Answer (score 1):

I would compare the key to the actual character, like

```
$("#txtInput").keydown(
  function (event) {
    if (('Ii'.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(event.which)) >= 0) && event.altKey === true) {
      console.log('Here you go');
      // Do stuff here 
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: You could also straight get use event.key and compare it to i. Check my snippet, works just as well.

Comment: In this case the key actually is ```"Dead"``` not ```"i"```, and even after checking for the key it doesn't work. Note that the code in the condition is executed but ```event.preventDefault()``` doesn't seem to be doing any effect, that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just compare to the key of the event and if its equal to 'i'. Feels like the most natural solution to me.

```js
$('#txtInput').keydown(function(e){
   if( e.altKey && e.key == 'i'){
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log("Blocked");
  }        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtInput">
```

Comment: I can type carets on that input, or any other characters preceeding by a dead key.

Comment: Well the question asked for a solution to block alt+i key combination and thats exactly what it does. Will edit my answer whatsoever, no worries :)

Comment: In this case the key actually is ```"Dead"``` not ```"i"```, and even after checking for the key it doesn't work. Note that the code in the condition is executed but ```event.preventDefault()``` doesn't seem to be doing any effect, that's the problem.

Comment: This has to do with keyboard layouts then. I cant reproduce your error. alt+i does absolutely nothing on my end. Maybe edit your question and say EXACTLY what is happening and what you want to prevent. T

Comment: I just tried your snippet on my windows machine and it works, so I'm assuming that this problem is specific to macbook's keyboard layout.

Comment: Go to this site and check what event.key is after you pressed i and alt and edit my snippet for your needs.

Comment: ```event.key``` is ```"Dead"```, and it's the same for these {alt+e, alt+u, alt+n, alt+`} too.